# Mail with attachement Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259

Tags: sql-server

I've tried to runa query :

```
DECLARE kursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT * FROM Certifications WHERE datediff(day,getdate(),CertificationDate)<3
DECLARE @Country VARCHAR(50), @Date date
OPEN kursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM kursor INTO @Country, @Date
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN 
   execute as login ='UserName'
   EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
    @recipients = 'nuliasz3@gmail.com',  
    @body = 'Duedate upcomming',
    @query= 'select @Country',
    @subject = 'Automated Message Certifiactions',
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
    @query_attachment_filename ='Country.csv'
   FETCH NEXT FROM kursor INTO @Country, @Date
   END
```

and i got an error. I thought that it is a problem with @query (although i really need to get this declared value in attachment)

So i tried a different example. More simplier to test

```
DECLARE kursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT * FROM Certifications WHERE datediff(day,getdate(),CertificationDate)<3
DECLARE @Country VARCHAR(50), @Date date
OPEN kursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM kursor INTO @Country, @Date
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN 
   execute as login ='UserName'
   EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
    @recipients = 'nuliasz3@gmail.com',  
    @body = 'Duedate upcomming',
    @query= 'select * from test.Certifications',
    @subject = 'Automated Message Certifiactions',
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
    @query_attachment_filename ='Country.csv'
   FETCH NEXT FROM kursor INTO @Country, @Date
   END
```

but it still shows Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259

Comment: For your second test... This is one of those occasions where the normal advice of "don't use 3-part object names" doesn't apply. Have you tried using something like `@query='select * from DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableOrViewName'` yet?

Comment: Using SQL Server as a mass-mailer: hammer looking for nail comes to mind. Have you considered a proper mass-mail application which gives usable error messages? Many of them can link into SQL Server to retrieve data

Comment: `select @Country` in the first version isn't going to work as the variable has a different scope. Likewise the second one looks like it needs an extra parameter `@execute_query_database = 'YourDB'`, otherwise it executes in the `msdb` system database

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes, i've tried. Doesn't work

Comment: @Charlieface I've also tried add `@execute_query_database`, but it does not work. Which applications do you recommend?

Comment: Start debugging by trying to send a simple piece of mail without any cursors, queries or whatnot. Even try the send test mail on SSMS when expanding Management / Database Mail.